# How to sort a FASTA file based on date?

Tags: python, pandas, biopython, fasta

I have a FASTA file that looks like this

```
>Spike|hCoV-19/Wuhan/WIV04/2019|2019-12-30|EPI_ISL_402124|Original|hCoV-19^^Hubei|Human|Wuhan Jinyintan Hospital|Wuhan Institute of Virology|Shi|China
MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNLTTRTQLPPAYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQDLFLPFFSNVTWFHAIHVSGTNGTKRFDNPVLPFNDGVYFASTEKSNIIRGWIFGTTLDSKTQSLLIVNNATNVVIKVCEFQFCNDPFLGVYYHKNNKSWMESEFRVYSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDLEGKQGNFKNLREFVFKNIDGYFKIYSKHTPINLVRDLPQGFSALEPLVDLPIGINITRFQTLLALHRSYLTPGDSSSGWTAGAAAYYVGYLQPRTFLLKYNENGTITDAVDCALDPLSETKCTLKSFTVEKGIYQTSNFRVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNCVADYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIADYNYKLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYLYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSTPCNGVEGFNCYFPLQSYGFQPTNGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVNFNFNGLTGTGVLTESNKKFLPFQQFGRDIADTTDAVRDPQTLEILDITPCSFGGVSVITPGTNTSNQVAVLYQDVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTWRVYSTGSNVFQTRAGCLIGAEHVNNSYECDIPIGAGICASYQTQTNSPRRARSVASQSIIAYTMSLGAENSVAYSNNSIAIPTNFTISVTTEILPVSMTKTSVDCTMYICGDSTECSNLLLQYGSFCTQLNRALTGIAVEQDKNTQEVFAQVKQIYKTPPIKDFGGFNFSQILPDPSKPSKRSFIEDLLFNKVTLADAGFIKQYGDCLGDIAARDLICAQKFNGLTVLPPLLTDEMIAQYTSALLAGTITSGWTFGAGAALQIPFAMQMAYRFNGIGVTQNVLYENQKLIANQFNSAIGKIQDSLSSTASALGKLQDVVNQNAQALNTLVKQLSSNFGAISSVLNDILSRLDKVEAEVQIDRLITGRLQSLQTYVTQQLIRAAEIRASANLAATKMSECVLGQSKRVDFCGKGYHLMSFPQSAPHGVVFLHVTYVPAQEKNFTTAPAICHDGKAHFPREGVFVSNGTHWFVTQRNFYEPQIITTDNTFVSGNCDVVIGIVNNTVYDPLQPELDSFKEELDKYFKNHTSPDVDLGDISGINASVVNIQKEIDRLNEVAKNLNESLIDLQELGKYEQYIKWPWYIWLGFIAGLIAIVMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDDSEPVLKGVKLHYT*
>Spike|hCoV-19/Philippines/PH-PGC-03696/2020|2020-12-23|EPI_ISL_2155626|Original|hCoV-19^^Central Luzon|Human|Research Institute for Tropical Medicine|Philippine Genome Center|Tablizo|Philippines
MFVFLVLLPLVFSQCVNLTTRTQLPPAYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQDLFLPFFSNVTWFHAIHVSGTNGTKRFDNPVLPFNDGVYFASTEKSNIIRGWIFGTTLDSKTQSLLIVNNATNVVIKVCEFQFCNDPFLGVYYHKNNKSWMESEFRVYSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDLEGKQGNFKNLREFVFKNIDGYFKIYSKHTPINLVRDLPQGFSALEPLVDLPIGINITRFQTLLALHRSYLTPGDSSSGWTAGAAAYYVGYLQPRTFLLKYNENGTITDAVDCALDPLSETKCTLKSFTVEKGIYQTSNFRVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNCVADYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIADYNYKLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYLYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSTPCNGVEGFNCYYPLQSYGFQPTNGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVNFNFNGLTGTGVLTESNKKFLPFQQFGRDIADTTDAVRDPQTLEILDITPCSFGGVSVITPGTNTSNQVAVLYQGVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTWRVYSTGSNVFQTRAGCLIGAEHVNNSYECDIPIGAGICASYQTQTNSPRRARSVASQSIIAYTMSLGAENSVAYSNNSIAIPTNFTISVTTEILPVSMTKTSVDCTMYICGDSTECSNLLLQYGSFCTQLNRALTGIAVEQDKNTQEVFAQVKQIYKTPPIKDFGGFNFSQILPDPSKPSKRSFIEDLLFNKVTLADAGFIKQYGDCLGDIAARDLICAQKFNGLTVLPPLLTDEMIAQYTSALLAGTITSGWTFGAGAALQIPFAMQMAYRFNGIGVTQNVLYENQKLIANQFNSAIGKIQDSLSSTASALGKLQDVVNQNAQALNTLVKQLSSNFGAISSVLNDILSRLDKVEAEVQIDRLITGRLQSLQTYVTQQLIRAAEIRASANLAATKMSECVLGQSKRVDFCGKGYHLMSFPQSAPHGVVFLHVTYVPAQEKNFTTAPAICHDGKAHFPREGVFVSNGTHWFVTQRNFYEPQIITTDNTFVSGNCDVVIGIVNNTVYDPLQPELDSFKEELDKYFKNHTSPDVDLGDISGINASVVNIQKEIDRLNEVAKNLNESLIDLQELGKYEQYIKWPWYIWLGFIAGLIAIVMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDDSEPVLKGVKLHYT*
>Spike|hCoV-19/Belgium/UZA-UA-8350/2021|2021-01-22|EPI_ISL_940774|Original|hCoV-19^^Berchem|Human|Platform BIS UZA/UAntwerpen|UAntwerp|Xavier|Belgium
MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNLTTRTQLPPAYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQDLFLPFFSNVTWFHAIHVSGTNGTKRFDNPVLPFNDGVYFASTEKSNIIRGWIFGTTLDSKTQSLLIVNNATNVVIKVCEFQFCNDPFLGVYYHKNNKSWMESEFRVYSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDLEGKQGNFKNLREFVFKNIDGYFKIYSKHTPINLVRDLPQGFSALEPLVDLPIGINITRFQTLLALHRSYLTPGDSSSGWTAGAAAYYVGYLQPRTFLLKYNENGTITDAVDCALDPLSETKCTLKSFTVEKGIYQTSNFRVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNTVADYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIADYNYKLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYLYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSTPCNGVEGFNCYFPLQSYGFQPTNGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVNFNFNGLTGTGVLTESNKKFLPFQQFGRDIADTTDAVRDPQTLEILDITPCSFGGVSVITPGTNTSNQVAVLYQGVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTWRVYSTGSNVFQTRAGCLIGAQHVNNSYECDIPIGAGICASYQTQTNSPRRARSVASQSIIAYTMSLGAENSVAYSNNSIAIPTNFTISVTTEILPVSMTKTSVDCTMYICGDSTECSNLLLQYGSFCT*
```

I need to sort these sequences based on the date column, I found this code in stack overflow but it doesn't do the job for

```
from Bio.SeqIO.FastaIO import SimpleFastaParser
import pandas as pd

with open('F:/newone.fasta') as fasta_file: 
    identifiers = []
    lengths = []
    seq = []
    for title, sequence in SimpleFastaParser(fasta_file):
        identifiers.append(title.split(None, 3)[0])  
        lengths.append(len(sequence))
        seq.append(sequence)
#converting lists to pandas Series    
s1 = pd.Series(identifiers, name='ID')
s2 = pd.Series(lengths, name='length')
s3 = pd.Series(seq, name='seq')


Qfasta = pd.DataFrame(dict(ID=s1, length=s2)).set_index(['ID'])
```

this is the error that happens with the second code and I don't know why this happens

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
in <module>
     12     SeqIO.write(records, output_file, "fasta")
     13 
---> 14 sort_fasta(input_file, output_file)

 in sort_fasta(input_file, output_file)
      8     def get_data(id_name):
      9         return (id_name.split("|")[2], seguid(id_name))
---> 10     dict_fasta = SeqIO.index(input_file, "fasta", key_function=get_data)
     11     records = (dict_fasta[i] for i in sorted(list(dict_fasta), reverse=True, key = lambda d: list(map(int, d[0].split('-')))))
     12     SeqIO.write(records, output_file, "fasta")

~\anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\Bio\SeqIO\__init__.py in index(filename, format, alphabet, key_function)
    873         key_function,
    874     )
--> 875     return _IndexedSeqFileDict(
    876         proxy_class(filename, format), key_function, repr, "SeqRecord"
    877     )

~\anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\Bio\File.py in __init__(self, random_access_proxy, key_function, repr, obj_repr)
    185             offset_iter = random_access_proxy
    186         offsets = {}
--> 187         for key, offset, length in offset_iter:
    188             # Note - we don't store the length because I want to minimise the
    189             # memory requirements. With the SQLite backend the length is kept

~\anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\Bio\File.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    181         self._obj_repr = obj_repr
    182         if key_function:
--> 183             offset_iter = ((key_function(k), o, l) for (k, o, l) in random_access_proxy)
    184         else:
    185             offset_iter = random_access_proxy

in get_data(id_name)
      7 def sort_fasta(input_file, output_file):
      8     def get_data(id_name):
----> 9         return (id_name.split("|")[2], seguid(id_name))
     10     dict_fasta = SeqIO.index(input_file, "fasta", key_function=get_data)
     11     records = (dict_fasta[i] for i in sorted(list(dict_fasta), reverse=True, key = lambda d: list(map(int, d[0].split('-')))))
```

what should I do about this?

Comment: Can you double check your data? This doesn't look like a valid fasta file, there is no `>` on front of the headers.

Comment: @mozway it has but unfortunately, stack overflow doesn't show that, now it is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following code the fasta entries in the input file are sorted and saved in the output file using the SeqIO index function. So, the function should also work with file having a big size that cannot be fitted in memory.

```py
import re
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.SeqUtils.CheckSum import seguid

input_file = "fasta.fasta"
output_file = "out.fasta"

def sort_fasta(input_file: str, output_file: str) -> None:
    def get_index_key(id_name: str) -> tuple:
        try:
            key = (re.search(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', id_name).group(), seguid(id_name))
        except AttributeError:
            key = ('0001-01-01', seguid(id_name))
        return key
    dict_fasta = SeqIO.index(input_file, "fasta", key_function=get_index_key)
    sorted_keys_by_date = sorted(list(dict_fasta), reverse=True, key = lambda d: list(map(int, d[0].split('-'))))
    records = (dict_fasta[i] for i in sorted_keys_by_date if i[0] != '0001-01-01')
    SeqIO.write(records, output_file, "fasta")

sort_fasta(input_file, output_file)
```

Comment: it has this error `IndexError: list index out of range` @Isy89

Comment: I edited the function. Can you post the full error trace? I cannot reproduce the index error

Comment: this is the error  @Isy89

Comment: Without the trace I can only assume the error is coming from the split() part. Are you using the same fasta file input as the one provided? Do the ids have the same structure, I assumed they are similar to the one you provided in the example. If this is not the case than you can have an index error, than a regex pattern like in the other answer may be better.

Comment: I edit my question and post the error, the FASTA file is exactly like the one that I post here @Isy89

Comment: thank you for your help and thank you for your edit, I need to use your code but it gave me `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` error and I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Probably there is some Id without a date. Is it possible in your case?

Comment: I think that is the case cause my file contains about 3 million sequences so I can't check all of them, if that is the case, what can I do about that? (btw it is ok to delete those sequences but how can I find them based on that my file is too large)

Comment: it is ok now, thank you

Comment: Do you mind accept my answer if it was useful to you? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string on `\n>`, and sort on the extracted date using a combination of `sorted` and `re.search` to set the date as `key`.

Use `reverse=True` as option for `sorted` to get the most recent date first.

I am assuming the string `fasta` as input here.

```
import re
sorted_fasta = ('>'+'\n>'.join(sorted(fasta[1:].strip().split('\n>'),
                                      key=lambda s: re.search(r'\|\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\|',
                                                              s).group()
                                      )
                               )
               )
```

example input:

```
>xxx|2020-12-30|xxx
NNN
>yyy|2020-12-23|yyy
NNN
>zzz|2021-01-22|zzz
NNN
```

matching output:

```
>yyy|2020-12-23|yyy
NNN
>xxx|2020-12-30|xxx
NNN
>zzz|2021-01-22|zzz
NNN
```